# Discrete subrings of $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Describe all discrete unital subrings of $\mathbb R$.

'Discrete subrings' = 'subrings which are discrete sets'

My attempt is as follows. The conjecture is that the only such subring is $\mathbb Z$. Let $R$ be a discrete subring of $\mathbb R$. Clearly, $\mathbb Z\subseteq R$ since $1\in R$ and hence $\pm n\in R$ for any integer $n$. It remains to show that $R$ contains nothing else than $\mathbb Z$.

I'm stuck at that point. Any suggestions/hints?

Comment: Why not $\Bbb{Q}$? How do you define discrete sets?

Comment: What do you mean by 'why not $\mathbb Q$'? $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. I define discrete sets just like here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteSet.html

Comment: If you define discreet sets in that sense, you have mention the topology as well. Otherwise $\Bbb{Q}$ is not dense in $\Bbb{R}$ equipped with the discreet topology.

Comment: @Bumblebee: I think you mean [discrete,](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discrete) not [discreet.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discreet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** If $R$ contains some $\alpha \notin \mathbb Z$, then by subtracting the integral part, $R$ contains some $0< \beta <1$.

Then $R$ contains $\beta^n$.

Comment: Is it really that easy? Since $\beta^n\in R$ for any $n\in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$ and since $\beta^n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, it follows that any neighborhood of $0\in R$ contains infinitely many elements of $R$, contradicting the discreteness of $R$.

Comment: @user525822 Yes, it is that easy.